# Vue Nuxtjs passing props

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, vuejs3

i get id is not defined , my props are not passed to the component, here is the index code.

id is not defined

```
<template>
  <div class="home-page">
    <h1>get latest News</h1>
    <post-preview
      id="1"
      thumbnail="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/26/09/41/chain-690088_1280.jpg"
      previewText="hello first "
      title="test"
    ></post-preview>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import PostPreview from "../components/posts/PostPreview";

export default {
  components: { PostPreview }
};
</script>
```

//////////////////
and here is the component im trying to get the props and use it in.

```
<template>
  <nuxt-link to="/posts/1">
    <article class="post-preview">
      <div
        class="post-thumbnail"
        :style="{
          backgroundImage: 'url(' + thumbnail + ')'
        }"
      ></div>
      <div class="post-content">
        <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
        <p>{{ previewText }}</p>
      </div>
    </article>
  </nuxt-link>
</template>

<script>
import ref from "vue";
props: [id, title, previewText, thumbnail];
export default {

};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define a component `props` in the `export default` scope .
***Note*** that if you are using an array for defining the component props you should define the props names as `string`

```
export default {
  props: ['id', 'title', 'previewText', 'thumbnail'],
...
}
```

Also do not use `ref()` , you can easily access your `props` with `this` keyword in your Vue instance methods or etc also without `this` keyword in your `template`

In your component template scope

```
    <div class="post-content">
      <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
      <p>{{ previewText }}</p>
    </div>
```

Or in the instance scope of the component

```
  created() {
    console.log(this.title);
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Try another way to init component, like this:

```
<template>
  <button>{{item.name}}</button>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    name: "my-item",
    props: {
      item: Object,
    },
  };
</script>

...

<template>
  <MyItem :item="item" />
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    components: { MyItem },
  };
</script>
```